# Joining with table where some values are missing

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have two tables, one containing customers and their ID and other containing orders with order information including id of customers. Problem is, not every customer has made an order, so when I do join their corresponding rows are missing

Furthermore, I want to do a group by clause on joined table to calculate total money spent per order, so even if I do left join, group by still omits the customers that have not done any orders. How can I fix this?

My query:

```
select alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email, sum(alp_orderline.order_price)
from alp_orderline
inner join alp_orders on alp_orderline.order_id = alp_orders.order_id
inner join alp_customer on alp_orders.cust_id = alp_customer.cust_id
group by alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email
```

Output:
[image: Table]

Desired output:

```
Cindy - Jones - XXX@hotmail.com - 307.94
Mitch - Edwards - XXX@gmail.com - 64
Betty - Sorenson - XXX@yahoo.com - 231
Fourth - Guy - his mail - 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want outer joins.  You should start with the table where you want to keep all the rows and then use `left join`:

```
select c.first, c.last, c.email, coalesce(sum(ol.order_price), 0)
from alp_customer c left join
     alp_orders o
     on o.cust_id = c.cust_id left join
     alp_orderline ol
     on ol.order_id = o.order_id
group by c.first, c.last, c.email;
```

Notes:

- The `coalesce()` replaces the `NULL` result with `0`, which you seem to want.
- This introduces table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- It starts with the customers table, because you want all customers.  And, all subsequent joins are `left join`s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use a `right join` just before `alp_customer on ..`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by changing the order of table and using `LEFT JOIN` like following.

```
select alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email, sum(alp_orderline.order_price)
from alp_customer
left join alp_orderline on alp_orders.cust_id = alp_customer.cust_id
left join alp_orders on alp_orderline.order_id = alp_orders.order_id
group by alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email
```